# Firebase sending and retrieving coordinates - javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

Just to sum this up, my question is properly sending and retrieving player coordinates.

---

I am trying to make a multiplayer game with Firebase. So, I began by making a player move around on the html canvas by pressing the arrow keys. Then, I have it so that when the player moves, it updates the player coordinates to the database. Here's my code for that:

```
if (keys[37])
    player.x -= player.speed;
    userRef.set({Coordinates: { x: player.x, y: player.y }});
if (keys[39])
    player.x += player.speed;
    userRef.set({Coordinates: { x: player.x, y: player.y }});
if (keys[38])
    player.y -= player.speed;
    userRef.set({Coordinates: { x: player.x, y: player.y }});
if (keys[40])
    player.y += player.speed;
    userRef.set({Coordinates: { x: player.x, y: player.y }});
```

And since I have the database open, I can see when I move my player(s), it updates to the database (I have two tabs open for testing the game). Now, to retrieve it, I have a simple test. Here's my code for retrieving:

```
ref.on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Then, I reload both tabs, and then on one, I don't move, but I open up the console. I then go to the other tab, and move the player around. But, on the tab with the console, (lagging very badly), it is printing

```
Object {Coordinates: Object}
```

---

Just to show, here's my **full code**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Game</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.3.2/firebase.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="c"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Refrence the database
            var ref = new Firebase("https://(I don't want you to know this url).firebaseIO.com/Users/Names");
            // Pre-defines user refrence
            var userRef;
            // Ask for username
            var userId = prompt("Username?");

            // Canvas and context
            var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvas.width = 300, canvas.height = 300;
            var width = canvas.width, height = canvas.height;

            // Player
            var player = {
                width: 30,
                height: 30,
                x: 10,
                y: 10,
                speed: 4,
                color: "green"
            };

            // Key listeners
            var keys = [];
            window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
                keys[e.keyCode] = true;
            }, false);
            window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
                keys[e.keyCode] = false;
            }, false);

            // Game Loop
            function game() {   
                // Moves the player when certain key pressed
                if (keys[37])
                    player.x -= player.speed;
                    userRef.set({Coordinates: { x: player.x, y: player.y }});
                if (keys[39])
                    player.x += player.speed;
                    userRef.set({Coordinates: { x: player.x, y: player.y }});
                if (keys[38])
                    player.y -= player.speed;
                    userRef.set({Coordinates: { x: player.x, y: player.y }});
                if (keys[40])
                    player.y += player.speed;
                    userRef.set({Coordinates: { x: player.x, y: player.y }});
                // Renders the background
                context.fillStyle = "black";
                context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
                // Renders the player
                context.fillStyle = player.color;
                context.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
                // Renders other players
                ref.on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
                    console.log(snapshot.val());
                });
                // Removes player data on disconnect
                userRef.onDisconnect().remove();
                // Game loop 
                requestAnimationFrame(game);
            }
            // Game loop
            requestAnimationFrame(game);

            // Checkes if username is taken
            ref.child(userId).once('value', function(snapshot) {
                var exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
                if (exists === false) {
                    // Continue if the username is not taken

                    // Makes user refrence
                    userRef = ref.child(userId);
                    userRef.set({Coordinates: { x: player.x, y: player.y }});

                    // Plays game function
                    game();
                } else {
                    // Reload page if the desired username is taken
                    location.reload();
                }
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am I just doing everything on in the Firebase aspect? Thanks.

Comment: Hey Sean. I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, so will just leave a comment for now. I think you'll probably want to print the object like this: `console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));`. This will print a textual (JSON) representation of your object.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Could you also recommend a way to get the coordinates? For example I made a variable named coords, which stores `JSON.stringify(snapshot.val());`. Then I have it output the coordinates to a paragraph, which output something like `{ Coordinates: { "x": 15, "y": 20 } }`. But, then if I try to have it output it by making the paragraph output `coords.Coordinates.x` for example, it lags really badly and doesn't output the x coordinate. Any thoughts?

Comment: Cool. Now you can see the coordinates in the logging output. You can access the values by `snapshot.val().Coordinates.x` (and `.y` of course). I'm not sure what lag you are experiencing. Firebase fires the `on(...` events immediately as you write the data on the same machine. So there should be no lag there. Can you set up the problem in a jsfiddle/jsbin so that I can look at it?

Comment: Here you go: https://jsbin.com/gubipewuhu/1/edit?html,output. I know that Firebase is great for this, I just know that I am doing something wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the JSBin. For me it works perfectly, the green box moves as soon as I press a key. I made a small change to it, adding the client-to-server latency in a textbox above the canvas. For me that shows a value around -30. What value do you get?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.